# How can I speed up performance of this Firestore query loop? Comparing phone contact list to Firestore database for matches

Tags: performance, loops, contacts, google-cloud-firestore

I am comparing a list of contacts' emails in the user's phone to a list of user's emails in my Firestore Database, and then creating a new list of "contactsInApp".

First, I get the entire collection of users from firestore database.  Then for each user, I create a forEach loop, checking each contact in my list of phone contacts for a match.  If there is a match, it creates a new list of "androidContactsInApp".  It works fine when there are a small amount of users, but when I tested it with 5,000 users, it takes much longer - about 30 seconds.  I thought firestore was supposed to scale well, so wondering if there is problem with my code.

Here is my code:

```
fsDB.collection("users")
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : documentSnapshots) {

                    String userEmail = document.get("email").toString();

                    for (UserInfoForRequest android_contact: arrayListAndroidContacts) {
                        String isEmailInDatabase = android_contact.getUserEmail();
                        String trimmedEmail = isEmailInDatabase.trim();
                        if (userEmail.equals(trimmedEmail)) {
                            String userID = document.getId();


                            UserInfoForRequest android_contact2 = new UserInfoForRequest();
                            android_contact2.setUserName(document.get("username").toString());
                            android_contact2.setUserEmail(userEmail);
                            android_contact2.setCurrentUID(currentUID);
                            android_contact2.setContactsUID(userID);
                            arrayListAndroidContactsInApp.add(android_contact2);

                        }


                    }

                }
                adapterWithApp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                adapterNoApp.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

I have also tried inverting the loop. Doing it that way, I get each contact within my list of phone contacts, and I perform a query for each phone contact.  This means I don't have download the entire collection of users.  This method is much, much slower -  multitudes slower.  I think that is because I perform separate, individual queries.   Here is my code:

```
        for (final UserInfoForRequest android_contact: arrayListAndroidContacts) {

            String contactsEmail = android_contact.getUserEmail();
            String trimmedEmail = contactsEmail.trim();

            fsDB.collection("users").whereEqualTo("email", trimmedEmail).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {

                    if (documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                        Log.d("FOUNDEMAIL", " document is empty ");

                    }
                    else {

                        List list = documentSnapshots.getDocuments();

                        DocumentSnapshot doc = (DocumentSnapshot) list.get(0);

                        UserInfoForRequest android_contact2 = new UserInfoForRequest();
                        android_contact2.setUserName(doc.get("username").toString());
                        android_contact2.setUserEmail(doc.get("email").toString());
                        android_contact2.setCurrentUID(currentUID);
                        android_contact2.setContactsUID(doc.getId());
                        arrayListAndroidContactsInApp.add(android_contact2);


                        adapterWithApp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        adapterNoApp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            })
```

**Edit**:  Ok, so I did some tests.  When I used "Snapshot Listener" instead of using .get, I was able to save 4 seconds to retrieve the document Snapshots, going from 27.5s down to 23.5 seconds.  I also found that the loop itself is only taking 4 seconds - the retrieval of documents takes 19.

I then deleted the 5,000 users and tested with 1,000 users.  The load time for 1,000 users is 6.5 seconds, and the loop itself was. 1 second.  Is this just an issue that firebase needs to address in order to speed this up?

Comment: Hi @Jeff are you able to speed up your search. Any solution?

Comment: Yes, I will post answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out a way to greatly speed up the search.

There isn't a problem with the code.  The problem is that it is just too intensive for the client device.

Instead, I used Cloud Functions, so the server, which has much greater power, itself handles the looping.

1. Get list of contacts on Device.
2. Send list of contacts (emails or phone number) to a specific document in firestore Database. i.e.. 
   `fsDB.doc("users/UID/device_contacts);`
3. Create a Cloud function that activates when that document is created... `exports.NewContactList = admin.firestore().doc('users/${UID}/device_contacts);`
4. That function reads the document, and looks for any "users" where their email or phone number == the phone or email in the doc.
5. It then puts those users into a new document - `users/UID/suggestedFriends`
6. Then the client device reads the list of suggested Friends from the created doc.

This process still takes time, but only on the 1st time you create the suggested list.  It also happens in the background, so the device isn't stalled.  I then also created a function that updates the list when new user is added to database or there is a new contact in the user's phone.

**EDIT**

The function I wrote...

```
exports.createdFriendListTest =     functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}/device_contacts/device_contacts').onCreate(event => {
console.log('test worked... function called after creating doc 1st time.');

const userID = event.params.userID;
const docWithContacts = event.data.data();
console.log(docWithContacts);

var promises = []; // to hold promises within the keyList.forEach loop.
const keyList = Object.keys(docWithContacts);
keyList.forEach(key => {

    var promise = admin.firestore().collection('users').where('email', '==', key).get().then(querySnapshot =>{
        console.log('querySnapshot obtained');
         if (querySnapshot.empty) {
             console.log('there is no user ', key, ' within database.');
             return true;
         } else {
             console.log('user, ', key, ' exists in database');
             querySnapshot.docs.forEach(docSnap => { 

                const userExistID = docSnap.id;
                console.log('that user ID is ', userExistID);

                const userData = docSnap.data();
                console.log('user Data', userData);

                const SuggestFriend = admin.firestore().doc(`users/${userID}/suggested_friends/${userExistID}`).set(userData);
                return SuggestFriend.then(result => {
                    console.log('suggested friend added');
                    return true;
                })
            })
         }
    })
    promises.push(promise);
})
return Promise.all(promises);
});
```

Comment: Hello @Jeff . Thanks for the answer. Can you please share cloud function you used, coz many of us are from java background, don't know node.js much .

Comment: Hi Karandeep, posted.

Comment: Thank you very much sir ! Can you remember how much faster this was ?

Comment: When the "suggested friends" list is created, it still takes a similar amount of time.  However, after that list is created, your app will just download that list directly, so it's nearly instant.  Adding a new contact or new user is extremely fast.